# Is was shocked adj or passive voice.?

Tags: ambiguity, parts-of-speech, participial-adjectives

Is was shocked adj or passive voice.?

> As she was shocked by the sad news,she didn't know what to do next.

I really confused was shocked in this sentence is whether adj or passive voice.

Comment: Do you think "shocked" describes her condition or do you think it describes something the sad news did?

Comment: And what other words that are obviously adjectives can you come up with that would plug in where *shocked* is?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I deleted my earlier comment.  Thanks for the clarification!